# getting SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules while working through the discord.js guide

Tags: javascript, async-await, discord, discord.js, async.js

I'm working through the guide for discord.js but when I try and set permissions for the slash commands I keep getting the SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules. not sure if I missed something or if it's something simple since I'm new to this but I couldn't find a solution for it.

here's the code from the guide that I'm trying to use

```
if (!client.application?.owner) await client.application?.fetch();

const command = await client.guilds.cache.get('123456789012345678')?.commands.fetch('876543210987654321');

const permissions = [
    {
        id: '224617799434108928',
        type: 'USER',
        permission: false,
    },
];

await command.permissions.add({ permissions });
```

Comment: What function is this inside? Mark that function as `async`.

Comment: Please show the function this is in. If it's not in a function, I would put it in one and make it `async` or put it in the top-level body of a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `await` in an `async`-marked function, if you haven't already.

Try the code below!

```js
// Change the name of the function to whatever name you want!
const discordFetchData = async () => {
  if (!client.application?.owner) await client.application?.fetch();

  const command = await client.guilds.cache.get('123456789012345678')?.commands.fetch('876543210987654321');

  const permissions = [
    {
      id: '224617799434108928',
      type: 'USER',
      permission: false,
    },
  ];

  await command.permissions.add({ permissions });
};

discordFetchData();
```

The code above will give you a basic understanding of what to do to your code (wrap it in an `async` function).

You can also make the function a self-calling, anonymous, asynchronous function, like below.

```js
(async () => {
  if (!client.application?.owner) await client.application?.fetch();

  const command = await client.guilds.cache.get('123456789012345678')?.commands.fetch('876543210987654321');

  const permissions = [
    {
      id: '224617799434108928',
      type: 'USER',
      permission: false,
    },
  ];

  await command.permissions.add({ permissions });
})();
```

In the end, both of these solutions will work!

---

For more information, visit [`async` function - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Answer (score 2):

I realized I didn't put it in a function, I don't know how I missed that but I guess I really needed a break since I got it right after I took one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this also:

```
(async function(){
   if (!client.application?.owner) await client.application?.fetch();
   //And more await calls...
})();
```